# iPhone API for recording sound and measuring the sound frequency and power(db)

Tags: iphone, audio, frequency, decibel

I want to develop a simple iPhone application which can record the external sounds, and measure the sound wave frequency and power in decibels, any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The section of the documentation labeled Audio & Video might be a good place to start.

Comment: I've googled this, but all what I found was talking about recording and saving sound clips into the iphone device,

Comment: If you can provide me with helpful links, that would be nice of you.

Comment: At which point you're going to have to open the files and read the 'raw' data which gives you amplitude/frequency/etc.  It will require learning about the file format you decide to write the output in.

Comment: If you save in MP3 (for example), you'll have to start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, It's ok to save the file into mp3 format, then how can I read the sound frequency and the sound power in decibels from the audio file, It would be great if you can give me links with technical links to the API I would use.

Comment: If the answer is wrong, tell me why it's WRONG. If you don't like the answer, answer it yourself.

Comment: Saving to a file, especially a compressed one like mp3, is wasteful though workable.  You should be able to just fill a memory buffer with some samples and process it.

Comment: Downvoted today, yet nobody owns up to why (after 6+ months as the accepted answer).

Comment: 3 down votes for an accepted answer - and I can't remove it because it's accepted